# bypass "private" in qooxdoo for testrunner

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

is there a convenient way to bypass the "private" visibility (*edit: that is, making them accessible for testing*) for qooxdoo class members for test runners?

The framework does provive a convenient test running infrastructure, so I wonder if there's some explicit mechanism. Just calling the method doesn't work (I think they are renamed by qooxdoo's generate.py script).

I want to have everything tested, so I need a way to get a test to those private methods, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, renaming private members is one of the optimizations that can be done by qooxdoo's toolchain. You can toggle any of these optimizations by overriding the "compile-options/code/optimize" config key of the generator job that compiles your application:
http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/tool/generator_config_ref.html#pages-tool-generator-config-ref-compile-options

In your case, the job to override is the one that generates the application containing your unit test classes. Adding this job to your config.json should do the trick:

```
"testrunner::build-tests-script" :
{
  "compile-options" :
  {
    "code" :
    {
      "=optimize" : ["variables", "basecalls", "strings", "variants"]
    }
  }
}
```